# NanoHttpd - return gzipped response

Tags: java, webserver, gzip, nanohttpd

How can I enable GZIP compression in [NanoHttpd](https://github.com/NanoHttpd/nanohttpd)?

Java code (starts web server and returns the same default response for any request):

```
package com.example;

import java.io.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;

import fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD;

import static fi.iki.elonen.NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.OK;
public class App extends NanoHTTPD {

    public App() throws IOException {
        super(8080);
        start(NanoHTTPD.SOCKET_READ_TIMEOUT, false);
    }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        new App();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        System.err.println("Couldn't start server:\n" + ioe);
    }
  }

  @Override
  public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    ByteArrayInputStream resBody = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[0]);
    try {
        resBody = new ByteArrayInputStream("{\"response\":1}".getBytes("UTF-8"));
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException ex) {
    }
    Response res = newChunkedResponse(OK, "application/json", resBody);

    res.setGzipEncoding(true);
    return res;
  }
}
```

And this request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8080
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9,ru;q=0.8
```

Produces this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK 
Content-Type: application/json
Date: Tue, 28 Aug 2018 11:39:12 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Transfer-Encoding: chunked

{"response":1}
```

Is there a way to enable GZIP for NanoHttpd responses?

Answer (score 0):

Add something like this to your server:

```
protected boolean useGzipWhenAccepted(Response r) {
    return true;
}
```

Also there's no need to use `res.setGzipEncoding(true);` as it's called automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if the header doesn't contains {'Accept-Encoding':'gzip'} or not even 'Accept-Encoding' header,then NanoHTTPD will default set useGzipEncode as false.To overcome this, you can gzip the data externally and pass the byte[] to the response.

```
public class Server extends NanoHTTPD {

  byte[] bArr;

  public Server(int port) {
    super(port);
  }

  @Override
  public Response serve(IHTTPSession session) {
    return newFixedLengthResponse(Response.Status.OK,"application/octect-stream",new ByteArrayInputStream(this.bArr),bArr.length);
  }

  public void compressWithGzip(byte[] bArr) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    try {
      GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(bout);
      gzip.write(bArr,0,bArr.length);
      gzip.close();
      setByteArray(bout.toByteArray());
      bout.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      //TODO
    }
  }

  public void setByteArray(byte[] byteArray) {
    this.bArr = byteArray;
  }
}
```